# Displaying an image from a databound path

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I'm trying to display a unique image in each row of a datagrid in a LightSwitch application.  The path to the image to display is found in a column of the datagrid's source.  The intent is to create a "product browser" that shows images of each product.  I have a table "products" with the following string fields:

- modelNumber
- modelDescription
- modelImagePath

This table is used as the data source for a search screen.  I need to display the image pointed to by the path in modelImagePath for each data row.  The data in modelImagePath would be something like "C:\Images\model00123.jpg".

Side Note:  I would prefer to avoid adding these images as embeded resources to the project, and instead be able to load external images from arbitrary paths, but I will concede to that if there is no other way.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this post in the LightSwitch forums which suggests the use of a RIA service to achieve what you are trying to achive...

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/d0ab8d85-faa5-4ca3-8d22-3d84737cb11e/

Cheers,

Paul